# Why did the trolls go into hiding during the events of The Long War?

Tags: terry-pratchett, the-long-earth, stephen-baxter

In the second book of the Long Earth franchise (The Long War) by Terry Pratchett and Stephen Baxter, the trolls of the long earth go into hiding.

What was the reason for this, and how do the characters in the book discover it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the question "Why did the trolls leave?" is that they were being mistreated and underappreciated, and being highly intelligent (far more so than most humans realized) they communicated between themselves using the "long call" and decided to go to a place where they would be treated better.

*The Long War* opens with an act of cruelty against one of the trolls, a female named Mary. GapSpace researchers tried to force her to give up her cub so they could experiment on it, she fought back to protect her child, and killed one of the researchers. This sets the tenor for humanity's new attitude to trolls - that they are dumb animals to be exploited.

Previously trolls and humans had interacted well:

> before Step Day most of what trolls knew and understood about humanity
> came from their experiences in places like Happy Landings, where they
> lived closely with humans. Peacefully, constructively . . .’
>
> What is happening now is that trolls are encountering ordinary folk.
> That is, idiots.’

Overseers of the work-gangs use whips on them, settlers view them as dangerous beasts to be shot if they stray out of their prescribed areas, and scientists vivisect them. In one incident

> The trolls were captured here for some kind of “experiment” in
> cross-breeding with other humanoids. Unsurprisingly they resisted and
> stepped away, heading due West, which led to a chase, and a male and
> two females being shot dead.

Incidents like this started happening more and more frequently

> Dumb people kept doing dumb things - such as shoot trolls, despite the
> intense political atmosphere after the Gap incident

(the Gap incident was the incident with Mary)

As a result, the trolls came to a decision.

> All the trolls everywhere sharing information. Well, it seems they’ve
> reached some kind of tipping point.’
>
> ‘Tipping point about what?’
>
> ‘About us. About humans. Our relationship with them. All over the Long
> Earth, they’re leaving - leaving the human colonies anyhow, it
> seems, any world where there’s a significant human presence. They’re
> not dumb animals, you see. They learn, and they modify their
> behaviour. And now, they’ve learned all they need to know about us.’

This was first realized by Sally Linsay. She had been concerned for a while about the mistreatment that the trolls had been receiving, and had been trying to get legislation passed to protect the trolls' rights. No detailed explanation is given how she put the pieces together, beyond saying that:

> Jansson didn’t bother asking how Sally knew about any of this [the
> reason for the trolls leaving]. She’d seen herself how Sally could
> move around the Long Earth, and she was somehow tuned into the trolls
> too, and their long call. To Jansson Sally was like a homespun
> embodiment of some all-pervasive intelligence agency, or a ubiquitous
> corporate presence, like the Black Corporation maybe. **Naturally Sally
> Linsay knew what was going on, across all the worlds**.